# Python - NoneType attribute has no 'left'

Tags: python

I am creating Code Generator from a labelled tree.This is the labelled tree which I am creating -
[image]

This is my code -

```
Reg_Stack = ['R5', 'R4', 'R3', 'R2', 'R1', 'R0']
Temp_Stack = ['T5', 'T4', 'T3', 'T2', 'T1', 'T0']
operator_precedence = {'(' : 0, ')' : 0, '+' : 1, '-' : 1, '*' : 2, '/' : 2}

def gen_code(n):
    if(n.left == None and n.right == None):
        print("MOV " + n.name + "," + Reg_Stack[-1])
    else:
        if(n.right.label == 0):
            gen_code(n.left)
            print(operator(n.value) + " " + n.name + "," + Reg_Stack[-1])

        elif((n.left.label < n.right.label) and (n.left.label < len(Reg_Stack))):
            swap()
            gen_code(n.left)
            R = Reg_Stack.pop()
            gen_code(n.left)
            print(operator(n.value) + " " + R + "," + Reg_Stack[-1])
            Reg_Stack.append(R)
            swap()

        elif((n.right.label < n.left.label) and (n.right.label < len(Reg_Stack))):
            gen_code(n.left)
            R = Reg_Stack.pop()
            gen_code(n.right)
            print(operator(n.value) + " " + R + "," + Reg_Stack[-1])
            Reg_Stack.append(R)

        else:
            gen_code(a.right)
            T = Temp_Stack.pop()
            print("MOV " + Reg_Stack[-1] + "," + T)
            gen_code(n.left)
            Temp_Stack.append(T)
            print(operator(n.value) + " " + T + "," + Reg_Stack[-1])

def operator(v):
    if(v == "+"):
        return "ADD"
    if(v == "-"):
        return "SUB"
    if(v == "*"):
        return "MUL"

def swap():
    a1 = Reg_Stack.pop()
    b1 = Temp_Stack.pop()
    Reg_Stack.append(b)
    Temp_Stack.append(a)

class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value='', lvalue=0, node1 = None, node2 = None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = node1
        self.right = node2
        self.label = lvalue


a = node('a', 1)
b = node('b', 1)
c = node('c', 0)
d = node('d', 1)
e = node('e', 0)
f = node('f', 1)

q1 = node('*', 1, b, c)
q2 = node('+', 2, a, q1)
q3 = node('*', 1, d, e)
q4 = node('+', 2, f, q3)

root = node('-', 0, q2, q4)
print(q4.left)
gen_code(root)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 73, in <module>
  File "python", line 30, in gen_code
  File "python", line 9, in gen_code
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right'
```

I ahve traced the program on paper after getting the error and the logic seems correct. Also, when I use simple print statement to see the contents of the attribute where the error is generated, it clearly shows that the position is not of NoneType. What am I missing?

Comment: Which is the line in question?

Comment: This is python. Why are you parenthesizing the if expressions? `if(n.left == None and n.right == None):` is exactly the same as `if n.left == None and n.right == None:`

Comment: at the top you are checking if both branches are null but what happens when only one of left or right is null? I don't see a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo ...

```
        else:
            gen_code(a.right)
```

Shouldn't that be `n.right`

Comment: For those of you that can, we have a close vote reason for this. Off-topic > Problem could not be reproduced/typographical error. Please use it (as this question is not useful to future visitors).

Comment: This is not off-topic or not reproduceable... If you copy/paste his code into a python file, you get the same error he did. This answer is correct.

Comment: @JakeGriffin It _is_ off-topic because it's useless. It should be closed, not answered.

Comment: It may not be useful to people later, but it *is* useful to the OP... He needed some help finding the error in his code. If you intend to close all questions that were found to just be bugs in the code (e.g., typos/logic errors), you'd have a *lot* of questions to close. I would agree that the question is not worthy of an upvote (because it isn't very useful to the general public), but why would you close and not answer the question? Why would you not want to help the one person that obviously is looking for a solution to the problem?

Comment: @JakeGriffin I'm not sure what your objection is. The question **is answered**. The purpose of StackOverflow is to create a database of programming knowledge, and this isn't a very good entry. It will likely never be helpful to anyone ever again. The OP has already gone home, got his fix. Now it's time to mark this as off-topic, because it is.

Comment: My objection was to Brett's statement, "it should be closed, *not answered*". After rereading the help pages on this site, I agree now that closing as off topic makes sense, but I disagree with discouraging people from helping the OP with a quick answer before doing so.

Comment: @JakeGriffin Ahh, sorry. I missed that. I disagree with that sentiment as well. Nothing wrong with posting an answer or helpful comment in the meantime. :)